# exp(X) has a normal distribution, what is the distribution of X?

Tags: normal-distribution

$\exp(X) $ has a normal distribution of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. What does it say of $X$ ? How do I sample $X$ from its distribution?

Can I simply apply the natural logarithm after having sampled $\exp(X)$?

**Edit - Background**:

In a paper [(table 2, page 7 - 138)](http://docdro.id/Ql6ih0k)  I can read: $exp(k_{a\_int})$ has a normal distribution N(−2.372, 1.092).

Comment: This is impossible because $P(\exp(X)<0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, that's why i find it weird. In a scientific paper, I can read: $ exp(X)$ has a normal distribution $N(-2.3,1.1)$.

Comment: What if $X=Z+iY$ with $Z$ real r.v. and $Y$ randomly chosen in $\{0,\pi \}$, for example ? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: I have edited the question providing a link.

Comment: having looked at the paper and some of the cited references, I don't think you should take this literally.  My guess is that they are trying to say that these quantities have a lognormal distribution.  Some evidence for this: $\log V_G \sim N(\log 0.15, .23^2)$ then its mean would be about .15, which is roughly consistent with table 1 of reference 16.  Similarly the mean of $t_{max}$ would be around 40 (ref 25 fig 4 p1053) and $k_{a int}$ would be around 0.1, very roughly agreeing with ref 26 table 4.

Comment: Yes, I have come to the same conclusion as you reading the references. Thank you a lot for taking the time to read those references ! You can post it as an answer, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

You have $P(X<a)=P(\exp(X)<\exp(a))=\int_{-\infty}^{\exp(a)}$ $f_{\mu,\sigma}(x) dx$ with normal density $f_{\mu,\sigma}$.

Comment: This seems to say that half the time, the value of $X$ is smaller than every real number. That seems weird, to say the least.

Comment: No idea why You think so. Which value do You mean?